# Creating jpg/png from .ppt/pptx file in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a pptx file on dropbox "https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5167jrxutvj37u/ASD.pptx?dl=0".

**I want to convert this file to slide images (jpg/png..) in my django template or django def function.**

I will use all the ppt images in my django template for some other operation.

Any suggestion???

Have searched for two three hours but not acc to my requirement. (ppshape, python-ppt etc)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv) to convert your `.ppt` file to PDF format , and then use [ImageMagick](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ImageMagick) to convert it to an image .

Comment: Can you please provide an tutorial to get snapshot of each slide?