# How to take save screenshot for each slide in pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

How can I save screenshot for each slide in pptx when use `python-pptx` package.

I have read [python-pptx.readthedocs.io](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and find [some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48455680/how-to-download-or-save-a-picture-from-a-powerpoint-ppt-with-python-pptx) maybe help, but still could not make it work.

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: I want to know how too ...

Comment: maybe this will help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150518/creating-jpg-png-from-ppt-pptx-file-in-django

Comment: https://www.convertapi.com/pptx-to-jpg  online API ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems difficult to perform such task in python-pptx package, see https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues/405 for more details.